# Resizing an image gives an Internal Server Error

Tags: php, imagick

```
$image = new Imagick("Koala.jpg");

$imageprops = $image->getImageGeometry();

if ($imageprops['width'] > 640) {
    $image->resizeImage(640,425, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    $image->writeImage("Koala_new.jpg");
}
```

I am trying to use Imagick to resize the Koala picture from the Windows 7 sample pictures. However, as soon as I run resizeImage, I get an error 500 200ms after sending the request to run this php file. I am running PHP 5.3.29, ImageMagick 6.8.6-9 and cgi/fastcgi are enabled in the configure command.

The error log shows the following:

```
[Mon Nov 03 20:19:56 2014] [warn] [client **.**.**.**] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Mon Nov 03 20:19:56 2014] [error] [client **.**.**.**] Premature end of script headers: imagetest.php
```

Is there something wrong with the FastCGI installation?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

So below i have given the code.

```
<?php

$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage('myimage.gif');    
$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');
$thumb->clear();
$thumb->destroy(); 

?>
```

Or, a shorter version of the same:

```
<?php

$thumb = new Imagick('myimage.gif');

$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');

$thumb->destroy(); 

?>
```

Beside that i have given you the two options for the same which ever is feasible with you can use.

Hope this may make your day !!

Waiting for you comments :)

Cheers :p :)